# How to use get_video_info Youtube

Tags: c#, youtube

I'm trying to develop a Youtube downloader.I need video mp4 stream urls and im trying to use get_video info check my source code

```
WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" + videoid +"&el=embedded&ps=default&eurl=&gl=US&hl=en");
            WebResponse webResp = req.GetResponse();


        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            webResp.Close();
```

This codes always get just a part of data maybe half.After decoding data just looks like this

```
 length_seconds=459&sffb=True&no_get_video_log=1&hl=en_US&vmap=<?xml+version="1.0"+encoding="UTF-8"?><vmap:VMAP+xmlns:vmap="http://www.iab.net/videosuite/vmap"+xmlns:yt="http://youtube.com"+version="1.0"><vmap:AdBreak+breakType="linear"+timeOffset="start"><vmap:AdSource+allowMultipleAds+=+"false"><vmap:VASTData><VAST+version="3.0"><Ad><Wrapper><AdSystem+version="1">YT:AdSense</AdSystem><VASTAdTagURI><![CDATA[https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?ad_type=text_image&channel=Vertical_1021+Vertical_1036+Vertical_1408+Vertical_211+Vertical_36+Vertical_590+Vertical_613+afv_overlay+afv_user_id_IO0szsIo5AKIFmbbhfxFqw+afv_user_lundgrenrob+invideo_overlay_480x70_cat10+yt_cid_679125+yt_mpvid_xxV6hpjhJlzWVUm7+yt_no_360+yt_no_3pas+yt_no_ap+yt_no_cp+yt_no_wa+ytdevice_1+ytdevicever_1.20170712+ytel_embedded+ytps_default&client=ca-pub-6219811747049371&dbp=ChZoWFduSWZZN2VpcG9CaWVYWnBPSndBEAEgASgA&description_url=http://www.youtube.com/video/rzkoQFbzmOk&eid=148648206&hl=en&host=ca-host-pub-7533488853144487&ht_id=5547539&loeid=9413138,9422596,9431012,9434289,9441394,9444433,9444893,9450707,9451825,9460350,9463578,9465813,9475121,9475579,9476699,9478199,9478523,9479324,9480114,9480538,9481125,9481317,9482504,9482602,9482851,9483147,9483258,9483501&osd=2&pucrd=CgYIABAAGAA&sdki=18803DAD&url=http://www.youtube.com/video/rzkoQFbzmOk&videoad_start_delay=0&v_p=JY0c2kM=&ytdevice=1&ytdevicever=1.20170712&yt_pt=APb3F2_FMmSD8mG8PMmMq7urTSbmCkJ0Bga4WDpKEQV0vAboVlPPijEHbExGYSXuMBmFcOJpCrpa2LhYnrkbgQbnWXXOarZjCKizS68OiIqOlB2GrZui5-ggUQ6aT7w6CaS_ifnYBnZXHpId9iX76vg6ufeyBrm43Pn8XtzfKSqvqvC1W8CRVv5me3zlMAU8-o1WblaDrL0g1b7SL7ot8DDGof6LRYQvNLPRCMZ6cjjIRMd62t7yetC6yMM2gjL_wZnSM_yKWhGZZgCWLQpIGY40tHARFRtOCCQsri5ttw&yt_vis=0]]></VASTAdTagURI><Impression><![CDATA[https://www.youtube.com/api/stats/ads?ver=2&ns=1&event=2&device=1&content_v=rzkoQFbzmOk&el=embedded&ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&devicever=1.20170712&asr=CgA&format=[FORMAT_NAMESPACE]_[FORMAT_TYPE]_[FORMAT_SUBTYPE]&break_type=[BREAK_TYPE]&conn=[CONN]&cpn=[CPN]&lact=[LACT]&m_pos=[MIDROLL_POS]&mt=[MT]&p_h=[P_H]&p_w=[P_W]&rwt=[RWT]&sdkv=[SDKV]&slot_pos=[SLOT_POS]&vis=[VIS]&vol=[VOL]&wt=[WT]&ad_cpn=[AD_CPN]&ad_id=[AD_ID]&ad_len=[AD_LEN]&ad_mt=[AD_MT]&ad_sys=[AD_SYS]&ad_v=[AD_V]&aqi=]]></Impression><Error><![CDATA[https://www.youtube.com/api/stats/ads?ver=2&ns=1&event=5&device=1&content_v=rzkoQFbzmOk&el=embedded&ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&devicever=1.20170712&format=[FORMAT_NAMESPACE]_[FORMAT_TYPE]_[FORMAT_SUBTYPE]&break_type=[BREAK_TYPE]&conn=[CONN]&cpn=[CPN]&lact=[LACT]&m_pos=[MIDROLL_POS]&mt=[MT]&p_h=[P_H]&p_w=[P_W]&rwt=[RWT]&sdkv=[SDKV]&slot_pos=[SLOT_POS]&vis=[VIS]&vol=[VOL]&wt=[WT]&ad_cpn=[AD_CPN]&ad_id=[AD_ID]&ad_len=[AD_LEN]&ad_mt=[AD_MT]&ad_sys=[AD_SYS]&ad_v=[AD_V]&blocking_error=[BLOCKING_ERROR]&error_msg=[ERROR_MSG]&ima_error=[IMA_ERROR]&internal_id=[INTERNAL_ID]&error_code=[YT_ERROR_CODE]&aqi=]]></Error><Creatives><Creative><NonLinearAds><TrackingEvents><Tracking+event="close"><![CDATA[https://www.youtube.com/api/stats/ads?ver=2&ns=1&event=4&device=1&content_v=rzkoQFbzmOk&el=embedded&ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&devicever=1.20170712&format=[FORMAT_NAMESPACE]_[FORMAT_TYPE]_[FORMAT_SUBTYPE]&break_type=[BREAK_TYPE]&conn=[CONN]&cpn=[CPN]&lact=[LACT]&m_pos=[MIDROLL_POS]&mt=[MT]&p_h=[P_H]&p_w=[P_W]&rwt=[RWT]&sdkv=[SDKV]&slot_pos=[SLOT_POS]&vis=[VIS]&vol=[VOL]&wt=[WT]&ad_cpn=[AD_CPN]&ad_id=[AD_ID]&ad_mt=[AD_MT]&ad_sys=[AD_SYS]&ad_v=[AD_V]&i_x=[I_X]&i_y=[I_Y]&aqi=]]></Tracking></TrackingEvents><NonLinear><NonLinearClickTracking><![CDATA[https://www.youtube.com/api/stats/ads?ver=2&ns=1&event=6&device=1&content_v=rzkoQFbzmOk&el=embedded&ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&devicever=1.20170712&format=[FORMAT_NAMESPACE]_[FORMAT_TYPE]_[FORMAT_SUBTYPE]&break_type=[BREAK_TYPE]&conn=[CONN]&cpn=[CPN]&lact=[LACT]&m_pos=[MIDROLL_POS]&mt=[MT]&p_h=[P_H]&p_w=[P_W]&rwt=[RWT]&sdkv=[SDKV]&slot_pos=[SLOT_POS]&vis=[VIS]&vol=[VOL]&wt=[WT]&ad_cpn=[AD_CPN]&ad_id=[AD_ID]&ad_len=[AD_LEN]&ad_mt=[AD_MT]&ad_sys=[AD_SYS]&ad_v=[AD_V]&i_x=[I_X]&i_y=[I_Y]&aqi=[AQI]]]></NonLinearClickTracking></NonLinear></NonLinearAds></Creative></Creatives><Extensions><Extension+type="waterfall"+fallback_index="1"/><Extension+type="activeview"><CustomTracking><Tracking+event="viewable_impression"><![CDATA[https://www.youtube.com/api/stats/ads?ver=2&ns=1&event=11&device=1&content_v=rzkoQFbzmOk&el=embedded&ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&devicever=1.20170712&format=[FORMAT_NAMESPACE]_[FORMAT_TYPE]_[FORMAT_SUBTYPE]&break_type=[BREAK_TYPE]&conn=[CONN]&cpn=[CPN]&lact=[LACT]&m_pos=[MIDROLL_POS]&mt=[MT]&p_h=[P_H]&p_w=[P_W]&rwt=[RWT]&sdkv=[SDKV]&slot_pos=[SLOT_POS]&vis=[VIS]&vol=[VOL]&wt=[WT]&ad_cpn=[AD_CPN]&ad_id=[AD_ID]&ad_len=[AD_LEN]&ad_mt=[AD_MT]&ad_sys=[AD_SYS]&ad_v=[AD_V]&aqi=]]></Tracking></CustomTracking></Extension></Extensions></Wrapper></Ad></VAST></vmap:VASTData></vmap:AdSource><vmap:TrackingEvents><vmap:Tracking+event="error"><![CDATA[https://www.youtube.com/api/stats/ads?ver=2&ns=1&event=1&device=1&content_v=rzkoQFbzmOk&el=embedded&ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&devicever=1.20170712&break_type=[BREAK_TYPE]&conn=[CONN]&cpn=[CPN]&lact=[LACT]&m_pos=[MIDROLL_POS]&mt=[MT]&p_h=[P_H]&p_w=[P_W]&rwt=[RWT]&sdkv=[SDKV]&slot_pos=[SLOT_POS]&vis=[VIS]&vol=[VOL]&wt=[WT]]]></vmap:Tracking></vmap:TrackingEvents><vmap:Extensions><vmap:Extension+type="YouTube"><yt:BreakProperty+break_type="BREAK_TYPE_PRE_ROLL"/></vmap:Extension></vmap:Extensions></vmap:AdBreak><vmap:AdBreak+breakType="linear"+timeOffset="end"><vmap:AdSource+allowMultipleAds+=+"false"><vmap:AdTagURI><![CDATA[https://www.youtube.com/get_midroll_info?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&m_pos=-1&index=1&token=AHArUmCi7IgSemIU1zQ6mZwxAcXsVLNJRz6p3BHXmckVo5VKctFqc4x6ksXsbH17HJT9kg5rEKPeTdDjb8Futt8whSRi64lqWuqukgtn7FROGCnEcb9nflpkqnys0RH7G3Felht1tx5IPbpnRh6iSc3pfhsvMMPvQRMUmRuozIyIZp7xVwhrQeYReh0leKubfaqXPRTWIGKf2u-2G082rpE8bhBTdY-ZINFWZXRhW3QAe2N9VTy4wbPGvNo7KAQ2qdBIoMJoJ9-LKEkHoensql4QkA8b3tQb9lJylNiD7N6DG4OQM0gGUrTW0xabLI-NLmeGOeRTCKr-&ad_block=[AD_BLOCK]&cpn=[CPN]&lact=[LACT]&tsla=[TSLA]&vis=[VIS]&c=WEB&cver=1.20170712]]></vmap:AdTagURI></vmap:AdSource><vmap:TrackingEvents><vmap:Tracking+event="error"><![CDATA[https://www.youtube.com/api/stats/ads?ver=2&ns=1&event=1&device=1&content_v=rzkoQFbzmOk&el=embedded&ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&devicever=1.20170712&break_type=[BREAK_TYPE]&conn=[CONN]&cpn=[CPN]&lact=[LACT]&m_pos=[MIDROLL_POS]&mt=[MT]&p_h=[P_H]&p_w=[P_W]&rwt=[RWT]&sdkv=[SDKV]&slot_pos=[SLOT_POS]&vis=[VIS]&vol=[VOL]&wt=[WT]]]></vmap:Tracking></vmap:TrackingEvents><vmap:Extensions><vmap:Extension+type="YouTube"><yt:BreakProperty+break_type="BREAK_TYPE_POST_ROLL"/></vmap:Extension></vmap:Extensions></vmap:AdBreak><vmap:Extensions><vmap:Extension+type="YouTube"><TrackingDecoration+match="^https?://((([a-z][a-z0-9.-]*\.)?(youtube|corp\.google).com/api/stats/ads)|((www\.)?youtube\.com/pagead/psul))"+headers="device,user"/><TrackingMacro+match="^https?://(secure\-uat\-dpr\.imrworldwide|secure\-gg\.imrworldwide|g\.scorecardresearch)\.com/"+macros="device_id"/><RegexUriMacroValidator><MacroToRegexUris+macro="NIELSEN_DEVICE_ID"><RegexUri+value="^https?://(secure\-uat\-dpr\.imrworldwide|secure\-gg\.imrworldwide|g\.scorecardresearch)\.com/"/></MacroToRegexUris><MacroToRegexUris+macro="COMSCORE_DEVICE_ID"><RegexUri+value="^https?://(secure\-uat\-dpr\.imrworldwide|secure\-gg\.imrworldwide|g\.scorecardresearch)\.com/"/></MacroToRegexUris><MacroToRegexUris+macro="MOAT_INIT"><RegexUri+value="^https?://yts\.moatads\.com"/><RegexUri+value="^https?://yts-testing\.moatads\.com"/><RegexUri+value="^https?://pagead2\.googlesyndication\.com/pagead/gen_204"/></MacroToRegexUris><MacroToRegexUris+macro="MOAT_VIEWABILITY"><RegexUri+value="^https?://[^.]*\.moatads\.com"/><RegexUri+value="^https?://pagead2\.googlesyndication\.com/pagead/gen_204"/><RegexUri+value="^https?://pubads\.g\.doubleclick\.net"/></MacroToRegexUris><MacroToRegexUris+macro="IAS_VIEWABILITY"><RegexUri+value="^https?://pm\.adsafeprotected\.com/youtube"/><RegexUri+value="^https?://pm\.test-adsafeprotected\.com/youtube"/><RegexUri+value="^https?://pagead2\.googlesyndication\.com/pagead/gen_204"/><RegexUri+value="^https?://pubads\.g\.doubleclick\.net"/></MacroToRegexUris><MacroToRegexUris+macro="DV_VIEWABILITY"><RegexUri+value="^https?://e[0-9]+\.yt\.srs\.doubleverify\.com"/><RegexUri+value="^https?://pagead2\.googlesyndication\.com/pagead/gen_204"/><RegexUri+value="^https?://pubads\.g\.doubleclick\.net"/></MacroToRegexUris><MacroToRegexUris+macro="GOOGLE_VIEWABILITY"><RegexUri+value="^https?://pagead2\.googlesyndication\.com"/><RegexUri+value="^https?://pubads\.g\.doubleclick\.net"/><RegexUri+value="^https?://googleads\.g\.doubleclick\.net"/><RegexUri+value="^https?://([a-z0-9]+\.)*youtube\.com"/><RegexUri+value="^https?://ad[\.-]([a-z0-9]+\.){0,1}doubleclick\.net"/><RegexUri+value="^https?://ade\.googlesyndication\.com"/></MacroToRegexUris></RegexUriMacroValidator></vmap:Extension></vmap:Extensions></vmap:VMAP>&encoded_ad_safety_reason=CgA&thumbnail_url=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rzkoQFbzmOk/default.jpg&innertube_api_key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8&atc=a=3&b=32vy80AGa-Bgh5X78MGIbmu2Kto&c=1500147363&d=1&e=rzkoQFbzmOk&c3a=26&c1a=1&c6a=1&hh=1HDgx0VAJl0SXzxb45QsrH_lAKVbaJ_K7iaF7J_ogxg&iv_load_policy=1&fade_out_start_milliseconds=0&instream_long=False&avg_rating=4.95149946213&of=hXWnIfY7eipoBieXZpOJwA&ismb=4450000&xhr_apiary_host=youtubei.youtube.com&loeid=9413138,9422596,9431012,9434289,9441394,9444433,9444893,9450707,9451825,9460350,9463578,9465813,9475121,9475579,9476699,9478199,9478523,9479324,9480114,9480538,9481125,9481317,9482504,9482602,9482851,9483147,9483258,9483501&enablecsi=1&account_playback_token=QUFFLUhqbG5Ta1k2bjVZNXE1S1RjeXJma0dYOVhJTlgtUXxBQ3Jtc0trRmxkREVqN1pxcjVPNTB3UUFxOG13RTNoVG1UQ0t4bDFNM3ZyQXhHbGtRQ1FyaWNYSGttZXlVTktEeGc3clQwNkFBNy1Bb08zTEJ6TDZNYkxWN2dwR1JfTWlQbnEyTE9DdDdNNUNGT1pTX3BrZU5aTQ==&fade_in_start_milliseconds=-3000&relative_loudness=0.760999679565&afv_ad_tag=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?ad_type=text_image&channel=Vertical_1021+Vertical_1036+Vertical_1408+Vertical_211+Vertical_36+Vertical_590+Vertical_613+afv_overlay+afv_user_id_IO0szsIo5AKIFmbbhfxFqw+afv_user_lundgrenrob+invideo_overlay_480x70_cat10+yt_cid_679125+yt_mpvid_xxV6hpjhJlzWVUm7+yt_no_360+yt_no_3pas+yt_no_ap+yt_no_cp+yt_no_wa+ytdevice_1+ytdevicever_1.20170712+ytel_embedded+ytps_default&client=ca-pub-6219811747049371&dbp=ChZoWFduSWZZN2VpcG9CaWVYWnBPSndBEAEgASgA&description_url=http://www.youtube.com/video/rzkoQFbzmOk&eid=148648206&hl=en&host=ca-host-pub-7533488853144487&ht_id=5547539&loeid=9413138,9422596,9431012,9434289,9441394,9444433,9444893,9450707,9451825,9460350,9463578,9465813,9475121,9475579,9476699,9478199,9478523,9479324,9480114,9480538,9481125,9481317,9482504,9482602,9482851,9483147,9483258,9483501&osd=2&pucrd=CgYIABAAGAA&sdki=18803DAD&url=http://www.youtube.com/video/rzkoQFbzmOk&v_p=JY0c2kM=&ytdevice=1&ytdevicever=1.20170712&yt_pt=APb3F2_FMmSD8mG8PMmMq7urTSbmCkJ0Bga4WDpKEQV0vAboVlPPijEHbExGYSXuMBmFcOJpCrpa2LhYnrkbgQbnWXXOarZjCKizS68OiIqOlB2GrZui5-ggUQ6aT7w6CaS_ifnYBnZXHpId9iX76vg6ufeyBrm43Pn8XtzfKSqvqvC1W8CRVv5me3zlMAU8-o1WblaDrL0g1b7SL7ot8DDGof6LRYQvNLPRCMZ6cjjIRMd62t7yetC6yMM2gjL_wZnSM_yKWhGZZgCWLQpIGY40tHARFRtOCCQsri5ttw&yt_vis=0&is_listed=1&cafe_experiment_id=148648206&mpvid=xxV6hpjhJlzWVUm7&cver=1.20170712&ptchn=IO0szsIo5AKIFmbbhfxFqw&fade_in_duration_milliseconds=1000&video_id=rzkoQFbzmOk&allow_html5_ads=1&dbp=Ch4KFmhYV25JZlk3ZWlwb0JpZVhacE9Kd0EQASABKAAQARgC&as_launched_in_country=1&iv_invideo_url=https://www.youtube.com/annotations_invideo?cap_hist=1&video_id=rzkoQFbzmOk&client=1&ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&csi_page_type=embed&keywords=rob+lundgren,cover,rock,metal,voice,vocal,live+vocal,lundgren,robin+lundgren,robin,nothing+else+matters,metallica,nem,nothing+else+matters+cover,acoustic+cover,n.e.m.,nem+cover,nothing+else+matters+acoustic+cover,metallica+cover,black+album&eventid=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&iv3_module=1&cr=US&root_ve_type=27240&cid=679125&fexp=9413138,9422596,9431012,9434289,9441394,9444433,9444893,9446364,9449243,9450707,9453897,9457141,9458230,9463578,9463594,9465813,9466793,9466795,9466797,9467217,9468797,9468799,9468805,9475121,9475579,9476699,9477080,9478199,9478523,9479324,9480114,9480475,9480538,9481125,9481317,9482504,9482602,9482648,9483147,9483258,9483501&innertube_context_client_version=1.20170712&author=Rob+Lundgren+Live+Vocals&cl=161729798&apiary_host=&allow_embed=1&ppv_remarketing_url=https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/971134070/?backend=innertube&cname=1&cver=1_20170712&data=backend=innertube;cname=1;cver=1_20170712;dactive=None;dynx_itemid=rzkoQFbzmOk;ptype=ppv&label=iuZUCLmC72YQ9qiJzwM&ptype=ppv&token=1&swf_player_response=1&idpj=-9&fmt_list=22/1280x720/9/0/115,43/640x360/99/0/0,18/640x360/9/0/115,36/320x180/99/1/0,17/176x144/99/1/0&probe_url=https://r5---sn-q4f7sn76.googlevideo.com/videogoodput?id=o-AEixTmbMug2neWtp5U1Tb-21J9uJ59IBSUY4nJ2T0axm&source=goodput&range=0-4999&expire=1500150962&ip=95.14.68.108&ms=pm&mm=35&pl=24&nh=IgpwZjAyLmRmdzA2Kgs2Ni4xMTAuNTcuNQ&sparams=id,source,range,expire,ip,ms,mm,pl,nh&signature=147AA9BCF3169578802C44A7735BBB7926C37092.5C2597F4730C259D6DDCD8AAAB093C906A61E8AB&key=cms1&itct=CAEQu2kiEwj407O1hIzVAhWCPxYKHVgsCTAo6NQB&shortform=True&t=1&watermark=,https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/watermark/youtube_watermark-vflHX6b6E.png,https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/watermark/youtube_hd_watermark-vflAzLcD6.png&host_language=en&excluded_ads=46=14_14;59=14_14;61=1_3,2_3;64=14_14;65=15_2,15_2_1,15_2_4,17_2,17_2_1;84=1_1,1_2,1_2_1,1_3,2_2,2_2_1,2_2_4,2_3,15_2,15_2_1,15_2_4,17_2,17_2_1;89=2_2,15_2;94=15_2,15_2_1,15_2_4,17_2,17_2_1&title=NOTHING+ELSE+MATTERS+(Live+Vocal+&+Acoustic+Cover)&innertube_api_version=v1&allow_ratings=1&pltype=content&ptk=BroadbandTV_Music&csn=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&oid=3q6zKQH3OljiViOJ67PJOw&status=ok&allow_below_the_player_companion=True&loudness=-20.2390003204&ad_slots=0,-1&url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=type=video/mp4;+codecs="avc1.64001F,+mp4a.40.2"&itag=22&quality=hd720&url=https://r1---sn-4g5e6nls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&lmt=1497979410219532&key=yt6&initcwndbps=556250&ipbits=0&mv=m&source=youtube&expire=1500168963&mn=sn-4g5e6nls&ratebypass=yes&mt=1500147287&pl=21&itag=22&ms=au&requiressl=yes&mime=video/mp4&id=o-AIlu0RkrqMnKv9EvUKiHDF8r6kAlczSgWVujKgm6Rz4V&dur=458.570&mm=31&ip=95.14.68.108&signature=5E6066364965F76E6BC61052DC402531E5F319B2.A3BBC0015021650C424E050CD546133A23578F5B&sparams=dur,ei,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,expire,type=video/webm;+codecs="vp8.0,+vorbis"&itag=43&quality=medium&url=https://r1---sn-4g5e6nls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&key=yt6&initcwndbps=556250&expire=1500168963&ratebypass=yes&clen=48022685&source=youtube&signature=771D35EFBBDC827F178E06B5B40372EA337A7E9F.6E06C0E37004690B1BF766340415170E296378ED&lmt=1497816143039353&ipbits=0&mv=m&gir=yes&mt=1500147287&pl=21&itag=43&ms=au&requiressl=yes&mime=video/webm&id=o-AIlu0RkrqMnKv9EvUKiHDF8r6kAlczSgWVujKgm6Rz4V&dur=0.000&mm=31&ip=95.14.68.108&mn=sn-4g5e6nls&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,expire,type=video/mp4;+codecs="avc1.42001E,+mp4a.40.2"&itag=18&quality=medium&url=https://r1---sn-4g5e6nls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&key=yt6&initcwndbps=556250&expire=1500168962&ratebypass=yes&clen=42156239&source=youtube&signature=B20E84210DACE3069FC90109B0B4CCD229468AD2.C02B2E5EF9C162E4E2201DA9062571FC6D511010&lmt=1497979373206161&ipbits=0&mv=m&gir=yes&mt=1500147287&pl=21&itag=18&ms=au&requiressl=yes&mime=video/mp4&id=o-AIlu0RkrqMnKv9EvUKiHDF8r6kAlczSgWVujKgm6Rz4V&dur=458.570&mm=31&ip=95.14.68.108&mn=sn-4g5e6nls&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,expire,type=video/3gpp;+codecs="mp4v.20.3,+mp4a.40.2"&itag=36&quality=small&url=https://r1---sn-4g5e6nls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&key=yt6&initcwndbps=556250&expire=1500168963&clen=12684319&source=youtube&signature=384C051D8C33CEFB6E28062E460398765AB5680D.265633CF03B2E0ED7DC72A3C6F3B788D6E10FEF1&lmt=1497814285338647&ipbits=0&mv=m&gir=yes&mt=1500147287&pl=21&itag=36&ms=au&requiressl=yes&mime=video/3gpp&id=o-AIlu0RkrqMnKv9EvUKiHDF8r6kAlczSgWVujKgm6Rz4V&dur=458.640&mm=31&ip=95.14.68.108&mn=sn-4g5e6nls&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,i...e&html5_subsegment_readahead_target_buffer_health_secs=0.5&report_promotes_terrorism_mobile_web=true&html5_disable_move_pssh_to_moov=true&html5_max_av_sync_drift=50&enable_playlist_multi_season=true&html5_suspend_manifest_on_pause=true&show_countdown_on_bumper=true&html5_always_reload_on_403=true&html5_repredict_interval_secs=0.0&signed_out_notifications_inbox=true&stop_using_ima_sdk_gpt_request_activity=true&kids_mqb_use_confirmed_safe_videos_only=true&html5_new_fallback=true&html5_subsegment_readahead_timeout_secs=2.0&android_native_live_enablement=true&html5_adjust_effective_request_size=true&html5_hopeless_mode_request_size_secs=40&mpu_visible_threshold_count=2&vss_dni_delayping=0&disable_new_pause_state3=true&html5_disable_non_contiguous=true&flex_theater_mode=true&lugash_header_warmup=true&html5_min_readbehind_cap_secs=0&youtubei_for_web=true&disable_reporting_html5_no_vast_ads_as_error=true&html5_vp9_live_whitelist=false&html5_suspended_state=true&html5_connect_timeout_secs=7.0&web_player_flash_fallback_killswitch=true&use_push_for_desktop_live_chat=true&html5_min_secs_between_format_selections=8.0&gapi_hint_params=m;/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.BznCEch7yrY.O/m=__features__/rt=j/d=1/rs=AHpOoo89FbxkNsIBOnpzYJliP4nzTuPXPg&view_count=138746&gut_tag=/4061/ytunknown/main&core_dbp=ChZoWFduSWZZN2VpcG9CaWVYWnBPSndBEAEgASgA&midroll_freqcap=600.0&apply_fade_on_midrolls=True&ad3_module=1&iv_allow_in_place_switch=1&adaptive_fmts=init=0-715&itag=137&fps=25&xtags=&url=https://r1---sn-4g5e6nls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&key=yt6&keepalive=yes&initcwndbps=556250&expire=1500168963&clen=142261087&source=youtube&signature=A81AFBC28F4D37951D2A3CA9F9370EBC07E410E4.BD5547C59956D93C2B351B302DFD86E85451A0CA&lmt=1497979028342198&ipbits=0&mv=m&gir=yes&mt=1500147287&pl=21&itag=137&ms=au&requiressl=yes&mime=video/mp4&id=o-AIlu0RkrqMnKv9EvUKiHDF8r6kAlczSgWVujKgm6Rz4V&dur=458.520&mm=31&ip=95.14.68.108&mn=sn-4g5e6nls&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,keepalive,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,expire&bitrate=3799443&type=video/mp4;+codecs="avc1.640028"&lmt=1497979028342198&projection_type=1&quality_label=1080p&index=716-1827&size=1920x1080&clen=142261087,init=0-242&itag=248&fps=25&xtags=&url=https://r1---sn-4g5e6nls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&key=yt6&keepalive=yes&initcwndbps=556250&expire=1500168963&clen=158398468&source=youtube&signature=CCC0D2490353B0065E5829F151305D95AEDE55B9.7CF4D0EE40ACB221728D8AFDF084E6A5DFABCD98&lmt=1497816474083876&ipbits=0&mv=m&gir=yes&mt=1500147287&pl=21&itag=248&ms=au&requiressl=yes&mime=video/webm&id=o-AIlu0RkrqMnKv9EvUKiHDF8r6kAlczSgWVujKgm6Rz4V&dur=458.480&mm=31&ip=95.14.68.108&mn=sn-4g5e6nls&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,keepalive,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,expire&bitrate=3123739&type=video/webm;+codecs="vp9"&lmt=1497816474083876&projection_type=1&quality_label=1080p&index=243-1842&size=1920x1080&clen=158398468,init=0-713&itag=136&fps=25&xtags=&url=https://r1---sn-4g5e6nls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&key=yt6&keepalive=yes&initcwndbps=556250&expire=1500168963&clen=79105869&source=youtube&signature=CDB118EDE7B63DDC9550F367E9F07830799655ED.D3EF922360819B481CF6ECC2763559AB0C3478AF&lmt=1497979016153211&ipbits=0&mv=m&gir=yes&mt=1500147287&pl=21&itag=136&ms=au&requiressl=yes&mime=video/mp4&id=o-AIlu0RkrqMnKv9EvUKiHDF8r6kAlczSgWVujKgm6Rz4V&dur=458.520&mm=31&ip=95.14.68.108&mn=sn-4g5e6nls&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,keepalive,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,expire&bitrate=2332623&type=video/mp4;+codecs="avc1.4d401f"&lmt=1497979016153211&projection_type=1&quality_label=720p&index=714-1825&size=1280x720&clen=79105869,init=0-242&itag=247&fps=25&xtags=&url=https://r1---sn-4g5e6nls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&key=yt6&keepalive=yes&initcwndbps=556250&expire=1500168963&clen=86507558&source=youtube&signature=93A41C597A00D1FA8E3D96781BF75C7DE64D9B1B.4DFE8C0F918A97505996A2CC7549D48D260BEBF5&lmt=1497816799001841&ipbits=0&mv=m&gir=yes&mt=1500147287&pl=21&itag=247&ms=au&requiressl=yes&mime=video/webm&id=o-AIlu0RkrqMnKv9EvUKiHDF8r6kAlczSgWVujKgm6Rz4V&dur=458.480&mm=31&ip=95.14.68.108&mn=sn-4g5e6nls&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,keepalive,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,expire&bitrate=1767900&type=video/webm;+codecs="vp9"&lmt=1497816799001841&projection_type=1&quality_label=720p&index=243-1834&size=1280x720&clen=86507558,init=0-714&itag=135&fps=25&xtags=&url=https://r1---sn-4g5e6nls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&key=yt6&keepalive=yes&initcwndbps=556250&expire=1500168963&clen=44918449&source=youtube&signature=1B71C220D58B22A6971AADFB121760093B6B2C16.6FFD92B792E9A31D2F69B194D3ED2D0548E7F245&lmt=1497979015179453&ipbits=0&mv=m&gir=yes&mt=1500147287&pl=21&itag=135&ms=au&requiressl=yes&mime=video/mp4&id=o-AIlu0RkrqMnKv9EvUKiHDF8r6kAlczSgWVujKgm6Rz4V&dur=458.520&mm=31&ip=95.14.68.108&mn=sn-4g5e6nls&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,keepalive,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,expire&bitrate=1168568&type=video/mp4;+codecs="avc1.4d401e"&lmt=1497979015179453&projection_type=1&quality_label=480p&index=715-1826&size=854x480&clen=44918449,init=0-242&itag=244&fps=25&xtags=&url=https://r1---sn-4g5e6nls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&key=yt6&keepalive=yes&initcwndbps=556250&expire=1500168963&clen=42553772&source=youtube&signature=946B26FD19005B4A77678CF58359B091AA196647.AF6B0B71C672F97F34B50DDFCE58B184A86DD311&lmt=1497816797643690&ipbits=0&mv=m&gir=yes&mt=1500147287&pl=21&itag=244&ms=au&requiressl=yes&mime=video/webm&id=o-AIlu0RkrqMnKv9EvUKiHDF8r6kAlczSgWVujKgm6Rz4V&dur=458.480&mm=31&ip=95.14.68.108&mn=sn-4g5e6nls&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,keepalive,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,expire&bitrate=891875&type=video/webm;+codecs="vp9"&lmt=1497816797643690&projection_type=1&quality_label=480p&index=243-1816&size=854x480&clen=42553772,init=0-714&itag=134&fps=25&xtags=&url=https://r1---sn-4g5e6nls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&key=yt6&keepalive=yes&initcwndbps=556250&expire=1500168963&clen=23508086&source=youtube&signature=1C0ECE53DF3F8D44509FB39E4E482A810BCC080E.916A6FF5E8B24D9B7A650A180C4984C15AB78E5B&lmt=1497979014659412&ipbits=0&mv=m&gir=yes&mt=1500147287&pl=21&itag=134&ms=au&requiressl=yes&mime=video/mp4&id=o-AIlu0RkrqMnKv9EvUKiHDF8r6kAlczSgWVujKgm6Rz4V&dur=458.520&mm=31&ip=95.14.68.108&mn=sn-4g5e6nls&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,keepalive,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,expire&bitrate=633970&type=video/mp4;+codecs="avc1.4d401e"&lmt=1497979014659412&projection_type=1&quality_label=360p&index=715-1826&size=640x360&clen=23508086,init=0-242&itag=243&fps=25&xtags=&url=https://r1---sn-4g5e6nls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&key=yt6&keepalive=yes&initcwndbps=556250&expire=1500168963&clen=23535825&source=youtube&signature=64D565D1DF5DE6B15DC5EE2EE615B2B69A27FD54.AA0F53B5E818B5653291E9755A2712E501028609&lmt=1497816797800637&ipbits=0&mv=m&gir=yes&mt=1500147287&pl=21&itag=243&ms=au&requiressl=yes&mime=video/webm&id=o-AIlu0RkrqMnKv9EvUKiHDF8r6kAlczSgWVujKgm6Rz4V&dur=458.480&mm=31&ip=95.14.68.108&mn=sn-4g5e6nls&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,keepalive,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,expire&bitrate=478817&type=video/webm;+codecs="vp9"&lmt=1497816797800637&projection_type=1&quality_label=360p&index=243-1788&size=640x360&clen=23535825,init=0-713&itag=133&fps=25&xtags=&url=https://r1---sn-4g5e6nls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&key=yt6&keepalive=yes&initcwndbps=556250&expire=1500168963&clen=13962368&source=youtube&signature=6CAFDFFD0FB4A1CCFDA3C54B7473FF2569EFE8AC.AEA43F8A56C9028D31932DBE1F7AF042E40099A7&lmt=1497979014440001&ipbits=0&mv=m&gir=yes&mt=1500147287&pl=21&itag=133&ms=au&requiressl=yes&mime=video/mp4&id=o-AIlu0RkrqMnKv9EvUKiHDF8r6kAlczSgWVujKgm6Rz4V&dur=458.520&mm=31&ip=95.14.68.108&mn=sn-4g5e6nls&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,keepalive,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,expire&bitrate=286948&type=video/mp4;+codecs="avc1.4d4015"&lmt=1497979014440001&projection_type=1&quality_label=240p&index=714-1825&size=426x240&clen=13962368,init=0-241&itag=242&fps=25&xtags=&url=https://r1---sn-4g5e6nls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=om5qWfj6NYL_WNjYpIAD&key=yt6&keepalive=yes&initcwndbps=556250&expire=1500168963&clen=12769212&source=youtube&signature=A49774FB936FBACCFF7993E6644AB6D35B87F6
```

You see its not full data I need from get_video_info.Its just a part of it.How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) it is much simpler than `HttpWebRequest`

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

`HttpClient` is the best of both worlds (i.e. `WebClient` and `HttpWebRequest`)

Comment: Thanks but I got same result