# YouTube Data API video duration is 1 second longer

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

For example, the HTTP request `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=kjDwZNs6GLs&part=contentDetails&key=[API_KEY]` gives back the below response payload:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "fMWPUAE-QPUqczFLIOqPLkA_HBs",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "JVU1XymxBIBUDHOdlmlwJ1nlhTM",
            "id": "4ZkEob55qso",
            "contentDetails": {
                "duration": "PT2M4S",
                "dimension": "2d",
                "definition": "sd",
                "caption": "false",
                "licensedContent": true,
                "contentRating": {},
                "projection": "rectangular"
            }
        }
    ],
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 1
    }
}
```

The duration in the JSON payload is **PT2M4S**, but if you go check the actual video on YouTube  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZkEob55qso the duration displayed in the video player is **2:03**. I couldn't find any mention of this discrepancy in the API documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.duration, does anyone know exactly why the YT Data API gives back a 1-second longer video duration?

Comment: No idea, honestly, but, try this: `https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=<VIDEO_ID>` - as is shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45122099/4092887) - and compare the results. Maybe consider post this issue on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) - search first if the issue is already posted. Test with other videos too if the same result appears. My best guess is that they round the duration "in milliseconds" and shows that rounded result.